# useradd: cannot lock /etc/subuid; try again later

Tags: dpkg, useradd

So, while trying to upgrade to 14.04 I encountered this error:

Could not calculate the upgrade

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

> Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message: 'E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.'

I looked into it and opened the /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log log file in a text editor, locating any "broken" packages and remove them with sudo apt-get remove . I had 33 broken packages.

I typed "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade" to see if there were any packages: there were 2 packages which didn't want to update: libboost-filesystem-dev and libboost-thread-dev, so i removed them to see if I was able to get a correct upgrade.

It didn't work.

I'm now getting an error about unresolved dependencies and can't do anything. I tried the following ways to get out of it:

1. sudo apt-get -f install, this is the output (it's in italian, sorry about that)

http://pastebin.com/y2DTqxdQ

Basing on this, it can't install this "usermetricsservice_1.1.1+13.10.20131003-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb" and even using software center opening it manually, gives error.

1. sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade, similar output as before

http://pastebin.com/k6DETpzV

This is the output with "sudo dpkg --configure -a" : http://pastebin.com/SEj83RSP

Edit: After rebooting, I managed to fix the broken dependencies through "sudo apt-get -f install", still I can't upgrade ubuntu for the same error as before and I'm not sure sure what's the problem here.

This is the output of "sudo lsof /etc/subuid"

```
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
  Output information may be incomplete.
```

Answer (score 2):

I had that error just one moment ago, and finally I've resolved.
I did this:

1- Try `$ sudo useradd nickname`.

2- The response, if you have the error, should be like this: 'useradd: existing lock file /etc/subgid.lock without a PID
useradd: cannot lock /etc/subgid, please try again.'

3- Now you have to remove all the files that are making the error, they are, in my case `subgid.lock`. (You can see that in the response says 'existing lock file /etc/subgid.lock', so you have to remove all files that is put in the response). Do this: `$ sudo mv subgid.lock /home/youruser/subuid.lock.sav`. Substituting `subgid.lock` for your error file.

4- Try again `$ sudo useradd nickname`. If shows other error file, remove it. If no more error files are there, you should get now the new user.

This was very useful for me, so I hope that you can fix the problem =). And sorry for my english because I'm spanish. Good bye and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar problem when trying to install *hadoop usergroup* `hduser` and I solved it by removing the two files. Here is the error I was getting:

```
useradd: existing lock file /etc/subuid.lock without a PID useradd: cannot lock /etc/subuid; try again later.
```

solution:

```
sudo rm /etc/subgid.lock
sudo rm /etc/subgid
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have another instance of useradd running at the time. You can figure this out using:

```
sudo lsof /etc/subuid
```

I don't have the file on my system, but it's provided by passwd package. I would recommend you verify that no process is blocking the file, then restart the system if it doesn't work.

Comment: This is the output, after restarting the system, the situation looks the same:

lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
Output information may be incomplete.

Comment: @fedexist you used sudo? Also, edit your question and add the output of `ls /etc/subuid`

Comment: Wait, "apt-get -f install" looks like it worked this one time. I'll see if i can update with more informations on the current situation.